# sxa rebuild -d command fails to execute

Tags: sxa

I'm working on an existing project which uses Sitecore 10.1.3 PRE and built using SXA.

There is a themes folder in the Solution which has the custom theme.

When I browse the local site, it doesn't have the css.

I'm new to SXA and trying to upload this theme to the local website.

When I run `sxa rebuild -d` from the `themes` folder, in the terminal, it throws this error:

```
error: D:\Projects\Myproject\theme\-\media\Themes\Myproject\Shared\Shared
Theme\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\universal.js:1   
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
D:\Projects\Myproject\theme\-\media\Themes\Myproject\Shared\Shared
Theme\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\universal.js   require() of ES
modules is not supported.   require() of
D:\Projects\Myproject\theme\-\media\Themes\Myproject\Shared\Shared
Theme\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\universal.js from
D:\Projects\Myproject\theme\-\media\Themes\Myproject\Shared\Shared
Theme\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js is an ES module file as
it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type":
"module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES
modules.   Instead rename universal.js to end in .cjs, change the
requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from
D:\Projects\Myproject\theme\-\media\Themes\Myproject\Shared\Shared
Theme\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\package.json.
```

I'm using `sc10.1.3` PRE with `Node 14.21.1`

Comment: Please provide more details on what you have tried and what you are expecting. SSE is not a diagnostic tool, for that you would be better off using the Slack channel or Community forums.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore helped me resolve this issue.

1. Navigate to this folder in the webroot
   `\App_Config\Include\z.Feature.Overrides\`

And rename the file `z.SPE.Sync.Enabler.Gulp.config.disabled to z.SPE.Sync.Enabler.Gulp.config`

2. Open this file in the solution folder
   `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes\MyProject\Shared\Shared Theme\gulp\config.js`

And replace the existing instance URL with your instance URL.

3. Open this file `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes\MyProject\Shared\Shared Theme\.eslintrc.js`

And comment the existing babel parser. Add this – parser: `‘@babel/eslint-parser’,`

4. Open this file `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes\MyProject\Shared\Shared Theme\package.json`

In devDependencies, modify the version for eslint – `"eslint": "^7.32.0",`

5. Open the terminal and set it to the theme’s root directory of the solution.
   In my case - `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes`

Run this command to register your hostname - `sxa register https://myprojectsc.dev.local`

6. Open the terminal and set it to the theme’s directory of the solution. `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes\MyProject\Shared\Shared Theme`
7. Run this command - `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`
8. Run this command `npm install`
9. Run this command `sxa init`
10. Run this command `gulp buildAll`

If there is any error saying gulp command is undefined, run this command to install gulp - `npm install -g gulp-cli`.
Once that is completed, run `gulp buildAll`
11. Run this command `gulp rebuildAll`
12. Run this command `sxa upload All`

Comment: Thank you! I just wasted half a day trying to figure out what went wrong before I came across this post

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with the different node versions, as you mentioned that you are working on an existing project.

So you can try two options here.

- Change `Node.js` version to the one required by this project and build again
- Stay on the `Node.js` version you have and remove the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file and do `npm install` again.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I have used Node 14.21.1 which was used to install the node_modules.
Tried 2nd step too. With no luck

Comment: @Qwerty Try this also. Make sure your package.json includes a line for "type": "module".